# Why is there no page layout for the Page content type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, page-layout

I have a pages library with two content types the out of the box **Page** and one a custom one with some custom metadata (from site columns) **Team_Resources**. Those I removed the other content types -- Article Page, Welcome Page, Error Page, etc.

For my custom content type I created a couple of page layouts using the design manager. That went well.

Now I want to create a few page layouts for the basic Page content type. But when I go into the design manager and select **Create a page layout** I don't see Page content type. I see my custom one and a bunch of other content types, but not Page by itself.

I've looked at several tutorials, but none of them show "Page" for the content type nor do they show the selector dropped down so I can see if other folks get Pages. Is it even supposed to be there?

How can I create a page layout to be associated with just the simple Page content type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no a page layout for Page Content type, it is by default. You can refer to the following screenshot about the default Page Layout content types:
[image]

When you click Page via New Document->Page, it will redirect to **CreatePage.aspx**, and you must to choose one Page Layout to create.
[image]

Assuming you choose "(Article Page) Body Only", after you create it, you will find its content type is **Article Page** instead of **Page**.
[image]

So, for your requirement, you can create a custom Page Content Type with a new Page Layout based on the existing one and design it as your requirement.

Comment: So strange that there is no way to just use the Page content type directly.